# mojave SMB randomly crashing, AFP is fine

Tags: macos, mac, network-shares, samba, smb

Building off my previous post that I can't edit or comment on: [Obnoxious intermittent SMB issues on mojave Mac Mini (2018) server](https://superuser.com/questions/1403645/obnoxious-intermittent-smb-issues-on-mojave-mac-mini-2018-server)

Ever since we installed a new Mac Mini (2018) with mojave server we keep having intermittent SMB issues.

Setup: Mac Mini (2018) Currently on 10.14.3. 32TB G Tech Studio XL (RAID 0) formatted Mac OS Extended drive that houses all shared folders and a 16TB G Tech Studio (RAID 0) formatted Mac OS Extended running time machine on the Mac Mini and 32TB G Tech Storage. DNS enabler running DNS services.

Important to note since my last post: I switched all of our shares to the 32TB External Drive which is now formatted Mac OS Extended. There is no longer anything shared from the internal server flash and nothing shared from any APFS drives.

Server has been more steady lately, with SMB only crashing occasionally. When this happens, AFP is of course still working fine. I have figured out the following procedure to reliably restore things to working order - restarting and waiting unknown amounts of time for things to start up again was not cutting it haha:

1. Restart the server
2. Turn off OD
3. Turn off SMB and AFP by unchecking the boxes under file sharing in the sharing pane of system preferences
4. Restart
5. Turn on OD
6. Turn on SMB and AFP reversing procedure above

After 2 crashes within 2 hours yesterday - 2:00PM CST and 4:30PM CST, I decided to go ahead and update from 10.14.3 to 10.14.4 last night, but have a feeling that won't do anything. See the following for the logs from yesterday:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QaS8ejvFXcAY1bK5WnT3IIP3CYqKVYKr/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JJjiCOullKjIgO1bUAz_PG_AslXNZZ5A/view?usp=sharing

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

While experiencing the same issue, I found you can troubleshoot by moving half of your Mac users to afp and see if the behavior stops. May logs looked the same as yours: look for `com.apple.xpc.launchd` entries.

My 2018 Mini log entry w/32 GB RAM sharing HFS:

```
Apr 30 14:42:32 Mac-mini-Server com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]  (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.504.100008.Aqua.Markreplyratherbyflyin9 athotmail.com): Caller not allowed to perform action: loginwindow.127, action = service removal, code = 150: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged, uid = 0, euid = 504, gid = 20, egid = 20, asid = 100008
```

I suspect one of your users is setting off SIP.